# asp.net api Endpoint not being hit from angular 8 client

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to call the refreshToken endpoint from the angular 8 client and it doesnt seem to hit. Could anybody spot the issue. I even tried 
matching the case of the parameters but it didnt make a difference.
I have verified that this.refreshLoginUrl is correct. Is it got to with sequence of parameters send or any other mismatch

client side

```
getRefreshLoginEndpoint<T>(): Observable<T> {

        let header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

        let params = new HttpParams()
            .append('refreshtoken', this.authService.refreshToken)
            .append('accesstoken', this.authService.accessToken)
            .append('username', this.authService.currentUser.userName)
            .append('userid', this.authService.currentUser.id)
           //.append('grant_type', 'refresh_token')
           //.append('scope', 'openid email phone profile offline_access roles')
           //.append('resource', window.location.origin);
        let requestBody = params.toString();
        return this.http.post<T>(this.refreshLoginUrl, requestBody, { headers: header })
        .pipe(catchError(error => {
            return this.handleError(error, () => this.getRefreshLoginEndpoint());
        }));
    }
```

serverside

```
    public class RefreshTokenModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }

  [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("token/refresh")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken(RefreshTokenModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "Invalid request data"
                });
            }

            var token = await _identityService.RefreshToken(model);

            if (token == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "Please check that your credentials are correct"
                });
            }

            return Ok(token);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead of `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`?

Comment: How about change **'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'** to **'Content-Type': 'application/json'** and on API add [FromBody] to RefreshTokenModel

Comment: _doesnt seem to hit_ are you getting a 404? where is the request being sent? what is the full path to your controller method? did you tried hitting that path from another client? eg. Postman.

Comment: And with JSON, your `requestBody` would be like `JSON.stringify({ refreshtoken: this.authService.refreshToken:  accesstoken, this.authService.accessToken, username: this.authService.currentUser.userName, userid: this.authService.currentUser.id })`.

Comment: I am able to call the endpoint via postman

Comment: Hi @Phat Huynh tried your suggestion but it didnt work

Comment: Can you post the response or error?

Comment: I am getting 401 status error

Answer (score 0):

NOT use httpParamas to send params, just a simple object

```
const params = {
     userID: this.authService.currentUser.id,
     userName:this.authService.currentUser.userName,
     accessToken:this.authService.accessToken,
     refreshToken:null
}
return this.http.post<T>(this.refreshLoginUrl, params)
    .pipe(catchError(error => {
        return this.handleError(error, () => this.getRefreshLoginEndpoint());
    }));
```

And use in your api [FromBody]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken([FromBody] RefreshTokenModel model){...}
```

NOTE: I supouse this.http is HttpClient, not the obsolete Http

Comment: I tried this. For some reason it is going to the catch block and getting 401 exception

Comment: Did you deliberately set refreshToken:null

Comment: Even setting it doesnt make difference. The enpoint doesnt hit at all

Comment: Do  Ineed to call .subscribe() explicitly